# How to Create a table structure in SQL without using the create command

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to Create a table structure in SQL without using the create command

in SQL Server  and Oracle DB

Comment: Why you wouldn't use the create statement?

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this, but even if I could - why would you want to do this? Why not just use a `create` statement?

Comment: Thank Mureinik this was interview question asked me so i just want to know is there any option using with out Create  command. as i know in oralce                                                                                                           CREATE TABLE dom AS SELECT * FROM dom1 WHERE 1=2

Answer (score 0):

One way to do in TSQL for `Temp tables` is:

Say you have a `TableA` and `TableB` and you want to create a table(structure) with  some columns from `TableA` and some from `TableB` without creating a permanent table then you can write as:

```
Select T1.ColA,T2.ColB
into #Temp -- only skeleton will be created
from TableA T1
join TableB T2 on T1.SomeCol= T2.Somecol
where T1.ColA = -1 -- some condition which can never be true
```

Answer (score 0):

you can Create table structure From multiple tables like

```
a)     SELECT * INTO TableB FROM TableA WHERE 1=0
b)     SELECT A.*,B.* INTO TableB  FROM TableA A INNER JOIN TABLEC C ON 1=1 WHERE 1=0
```